# "Polishing Saint-in-the-Box"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, religion

I'm reading *St. Lucy's School for Girls Raised by Wolves* by Karen Russell.  I haven't been able to figure out exactly what "Saint-in-the-Box" means (I googled it) in the following:

> 'Does Mirabella try to earn Skill Points by shelling walnuts and polishing Saint-in-the-Box?  No.  Does Mirabella even know how to say the word walnut?  Has she learned how to say anything besides a sinful "HraaaHA!" as she commits frottage against the organ pipes? No.'

The school has nuns.

Comment: I guess it's just a statue of a saint that is kept in a (glass?) box and one of the chores the girls have to perform is keeping it clean?

Comment: As you discovered, it's not a common word or phrase that has been captured in a dictionary. Making this a literature interpretation request, so you're asking the wrong experts. Might try the [literature.se] beta.

Comment: It seems that Mirabella believes that frottage is more worthy than a polishing a canned saint.

Comment: "Commits frottage against the organ pipes" refers to a solitary sexual activity. This leads me to think that "polishing saint-in-the-box" means self-stimulation of the clitoris. This is something to ask someone familiar with the author's work. As noted above, try [literature.se].

Comment: I had the idea of looking for this in Spanish.  After trying a couple different formulations, I arrived at *retablo*, which is apparently *altarpiece*.  I hope someone who understands Catholicism or religious artefacts will respond.

Comment: @MetaEd But the frottage is being contrasted with the thing she should be doing, not likened to it. There is nothing in the text to suggest the students are being encouraged to gain 'skill points' in masturbation. http://make-space.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/karen-russell-st-lucys-school-for-girls-raised-by-wolves.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in the catholic world a saint in a box is a figurine of a saint:

> From Generations Religious Gifts... your Patron Saint Superstore! The Most Sacred Heart of Jesus 3.5 inch Saint in a Box Religious Statue Figurine A small full color resin statue perfect for personal devotion or gift giving! This wonderful small statue is part of the **Saints in a Box** line of statues by Roman, Inc that includes many of the best known and beloved Catholic saints, popes, and images of and devotions to Jesus and Mary. ***Picture note: The picture of the St. Joseph box is only meant to show the detail of the box each statue comes in in the Saint in a Box line of statues. Any order will NOT come with a St. Joseph statue or box in  ...

From  [a web shop](http://www.qju88.com/jesus-figurine.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Having found an online source for the story and read it, the term 'saint-in-the-box' would seem to refer to some object that would be commonly found in a catholic boarding school. 
There seem to be three possibilities:

- A literal saint in a box. Or at least part of a saint. Such as the [Reliquary of St. Francis Xavier's humerus](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Xavier#) at St. Joseph's Church, Macao 
  [image: Reliquary of St. Francis Xavier's humerus]
  Reliquaries may also be on a more modest scale, such as the [Monymusk Reliquary](https://www.nms.ac.uk/explore-our-collections/stories/scottish-history-and-archaeology/monymusk-reliquary/)[image: House shaped reliquary decorated in silver and bronze]
- A [plaster or wax sculpture of a saint in a protective case.](http://artedeluniverso.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/saint-anthony-statue-ivory-antique-wood.html?m=1) I had assumed these would be common, but pictures are few online. It is possible that these are so ubiquitous that they go unnoted. 
  [image: St Anthony in wood and glass case]
- a painted icon of a saint in a wooden case which can be opened and closed, such as [this Flemish example](http://www.artnet.com/artists/flemish-school-antwerp-16/a-triptych-saint-luke-painting-the-virgin-the-GOGhNwqza6cQm7VIezqe8Q2) from the 16thC
  [image: Saint Luke painting the virgin Mary]

Reliquaries seem more likely to be held in churches than schools and the folding icons more generally depict the Virgin Mary. This leaves the most likely 'saint in a box' as statue of the eponymous St Lucy, displayed in a glass case with wooden or metal framing.